# In python, If cell contains specific string, remove specific string and while moving specific string to a different cell

Tags: python, pandas, string, contains

During data entry, Some of the States were added to the same cell as the Address line. The city and state vary and are generally unknown. There are also some cases of a `,`  that would need to be removed.

```
          AddrLines           AddrCity        AddrState
0        123 street         Titusville FL         NaN
1        456 road           Viera FL              NaN
2        789 place          Melbourne, Fl         NaN
3        001 ave            Wright                VA
```

My goal is to clean up the City column while moving the state over to the State column. Something like this, but removing the state and the `,` at the same time.

```
df.loc[(df['AddrCity'].str.contains(' Fl')),'AddrState'] = 'FL'
df.loc[(df['AddrCity'].str.contains(' FL')),'AddrState'] = 'FL'
df.loc[(df['AddrCity'].str.contains(', Fl')),'AddrState'] = 'FL'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this by performing the following

```
df1[['AddrCity', 'State_Holder']] = df1['AddrCity'].str.replace(', ', ' ').str.replace(' ', ', ').str.split(', ', 1, expand = True)
df1['AddrState'] = np.where(df1['AddrState'].isna(), df1['State_Holder'], df1['AddrState'])
df1.drop(columns = ['State_Holder'])
```

Comment: This worked well, but ```State_Holder``` was not actually dropping. I added to that last line to fix it. ```df1 =  df1.drop(columns = ['State_Holder'])```